# Cocos2d Game Lost Focus When we click Volume Up or Volume Down Button On Motorola xoom

Tags: android, motorola, xoom, cocos2d-android

I am developing a game using **Cocos2d FrameWork** in Android.

I encountered a problem while testing on **Motorola Xoom**.

What I want to do :

- When User pressed *Volume up* and *Volume down* Button. All the Animation should play with sound .

But What actually Happened:

- When I pressed volume up down button on Motorola Xoom than My Game Lost Focus and all Animation Paused but sound is playing according to the volume button settings.

This is only when I test my Application in **Honey Comb OS**.

I am using `onWindowFocusChanged` method to Resume Game Play.

Anyone having encounter this type of problem ?
Please let me know if anyone have solution for this .

Thanks.

Comment: anyone has solution for this ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found answer myself ..

Here is the solution of this issue ..

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{
    synchronized(sGLThreadManager) {
    //mHasFocus = hasFocus;
    mHasFocus = true;
    sGLThreadManager.notifyAll();
    }
    if (LOG_SURFACE) 
    {
        Log.i("Main thread", "Focus " + (mHasFocus ? "gained" : "lost"));
    }
}
```

just change mHasFocus = true in GLSurfaceView class of Cocos2d android ...

Comment: cocos2d-android version is very buggy. It needs to be cleanup.